PullToRefreshBox inside LazyColumn scrolls the parent column on canceled pull gesture
I have a LazyColumn that serves as the main scrollable container, with PullToRefreshBox nested inside one of its items. The PullToRefreshBox wraps a horizontal pager (HorizontalClassPager) that contains its own internal LazyColumn.
Code:
LazyColumn (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(scaffoldPadding)
    ) {
        item {
            ...
        }
        item {
            Column(
                Modifier.padding(horizontal = 18.dp)
            ) {
                PullToRefreshBox(
                    state = pullToRefreshState,
                    isRefreshing = state.isRefreshing,
                    onRefresh = {
                        //
                    }
                ) { 
                    //contains lazy column inside
                    HorizontalClassPager(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxHeight(fraction = 0.8f),
                        state = pagerState,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

The setup works as expected most of the time. However, if I scroll down the main LazyColumn to bring the PullToRefreshBox fully into view, and then start a pull-to-refresh gesture (but do not complete it), the gesture is canceled. Instead of staying in place, the main LazyColumn scrolls further down by the amount of the canceled pull gesture.
It seems that the pull gesture is partially intercepted by the LazyColumn, causing unintended scrolling. How can I prevent the parent LazyColumn from reacting to canceled pull gestures in the child PullToRefreshBox?
Example gif: gif

Is it really necessary in your case that your outer Composable is a LazyColumn? Why do you need it`?

@BenjyTec, LazyColumn is necessary because without it, users wouldn’t be able to view elements of HorizontalClassPager, especially in  landscape mode.

You are having two LazyColumns, correct? One around the HorizontalClassPager and one inside it. Do you really need both?

@BenjyTec, yes you are right, i have one around and one inside and i need both of them
